# How can I resize or transform the selected part of an image in paint shop pro?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, resize, transform, corel-paint-shop-pro

I have some experience with adobe photishop. I know how to select a part of an image (or layer) and to resize/transform it (ctrl-T).

Because  I do not have Adobe photoshop at home, but paint shop pro instead (came free with the notebook), I am looking for the same operation in paint shop pro. I have a layer which is to large for the image it is pasted in and therefore want to have it smaller. I cannot find the way to do that in paint shop pro.

How can I perform this operation in paint shop pro?

Comment: I don't use Paint Shop Pro, but in Photoshop you'd likely make a selection, copy and paste to a new layer, and then scale it.  I should imagine it's fairly similar in Paint Shop Pro, or any raster image editor that uses layers.

Comment: Yes, I know. But somehow, I haven't found yet how to resize this specific layer.

Comment: Found this: [scaling and transforming photos with pick tool](http://product.corel.com/help/PaintShop-Pro/540214299/Main/EN/Doc/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Corel-PaintShop-Pro-Transforming-with-the-Pick-tool.html&single=true). So, it's not a specific scale tool as such. Looks like you can just click and drag the corner handles.